# How to print webdriver listener logs in extent report instead of writing in test cases

Tags: selenium-webdriver, listener, selenium-extent-report

I actually need to print these webdriver logs in extent report , these logs are printing in console but i need to have in my extent report too.

I dont want to write "test.log(Status.info , "Before navigating to")" in my test cases
 one ques, can we implement extent report with webdriver listener

These logs are printing in my console .same these logs i need in my extent report

```
         Trying to find Element By : By.xpath: //a[@class='account_icon']
Found Element By : By.xpath: //a[@class='account_icon']
Trying to click on: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (75240300120748eac34cac341b58ae6b)] -> xpath: //a[@class='account_icon']]
Clicked on: [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (75240300120748eac34cac341b58ae6b)] -> xpath: //a[@class='account_icon']]
Trying to find Element By : By.xpath: .//*[@id='log']
Found Element By : By.xpath: .//*[@id='log']
Trying to find Element By : By.id: pwd
Found Element By : By.id: pwd
Property file loaded
Trying to find Element By : By.xpath: //img[@alt='home']
Found Element By : By.xpath: //img[@alt='home']
```

Comment: Please share your trial code, how do you use Extent Report with version info.

Comment: @IshitaShah I didnt used extent report, iam about too, i dont know how to implement in this listener class, going to use extent report 3.0

Comment: You may refer official example and try with basic implementation.
http://extentreports.com/docs/versions/3/java/#examples

Comment: any tutorial videos regarding this

Comment: @IshitaShah it didnt work, i need to impelement with webdriver listener

Comment: Share your trial code

Comment: @IshitaShah done ,could u check

Comment: What do you want to log in extent report ?

Comment: @IshitaShah i have edited my ques, i need my console logs to be printed in extent report,

Comment: I request you, Please refer how to ask question with minimum required information, trial code, expected result, errors with proper format. You can simply refer my questions even.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180340/discussion-between-jino-and-ishita-shah).